# Types "not found" by compiler despite existing, and IntelliSense finding them?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've started getting strange errors when compiling along the lines of:

```
warning  in ./src/mixins/RefMixin.ts
"export 'PmAttrs' was not found in 'src/types/pm'
```

... and many many others, with the common theme being that it's a type or interface exported from another .ts module.

Note that not only is the export actually there, but IntelliSense sees it and interprets it properly. It's only when the project is actually compiled (e.g. when running the "dev" run command) that I see this compiler warning.

The really odd thing is that this doesn't happen right away, and I don't know why it starts occurring. In other words, I export a type and read it and it works fine, but sometimes, at some point down the line, it starts throwing this compiler warning saying it's "not found" despite is declaration and export not changing at all.

I'm guessing that I'm not following some sort of rule that it's not telling me about, and it's responding to that by not importing those types, but does anyone have any idea what that rule might be?

Comment: Ideally, we need a minimal reproduction of the issue and probably some information about your tools. If you simply run the `tsc` command, do you see the same issue or is there maybe a bug with your editor?

Comment: @Fenton Thanks for pointing in the direction of looking closer at tooling. After doing some upgrades / reinstalls, this error went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Fenton's suggestion, I looked closer at tooling, and some reinstalls / upgrades fixed the issue.

I'm using Quasar and the issue may have been with using an out of date Typescript template for it.